# How to get the last List of a JAVA class

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, xsd

I'm trying to create a class which has an ArrayList.
For example:

```
public class SubCategory {
    protected String nameOfCategory;
    @XmlElement(required = true)
    protected String link;
    @XmlElementRef
    protected List<SubCategory> supCategory;...
}
```

How to get the last List of SubCategory? I use the JAXB for xml file and the xsd file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    targetNamespace="http://www.example.org/CategoriesTree" xmlns="http://www.example.org/CategoriesTree"
    elementFormDefault="qualified">

    <xs:element name="Categories">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="mainCategory" type="subCategory" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>

    <xs:complexType name="subCategory">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="nameOfCategory" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="link" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="subCategory" type="subCategory" maxOccurs="unbounded"
                minOccurs="0"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

---

Yes I have this method but I have to go to last element in tree for example:
how to get the last element?

```
<code>
<subCategory>
  <nameOfCategory>Ordnungsmittel / Ablagemittel</nameOfCategory>
  <link>link=Ordnungsmittel / Ablagemittel</link>
  <subCategory>
    <nameOfCategory>Ordnungsmittel / Ablagemittel</nameOfCategory>
    <link>link=Ordnungsmittel / Ablagemittel</link>
    <subCategory>
       <nameOfCategory>Last</nameOfCategory>
        <link>link=Last</link>
    </subCategory>
   </subCategory>
</subCategory>
</code>
```

Comment: *"How to get the last List of SubCategory?"* - I have no idea what you are asking.  Please rephrase the question so that we can understand it.

Comment: I think the OP is asking if he can make a list in a class contain that class itself as the generic (if that makes sense).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure what you want to accomplish. I grabbed a generated class from one of my projects and a list, defined like you posted in the XSD, will be created like this in the Java class:

```
@XmlElement(required = true)
protected List<Manager> manager;

public List<Manager> getManager() {
    if (manager == null) {
        manager = new ArrayList<Manager>();
    }
    return this.manager;
}
```

If you want to add something to the list, you'll have to use the get method as well to obtain a reference.

Answer (score 0):

> How to get the last List of SubCategory?

Since you have a tree where each node is of the same type (`SubCategory`), you could write a recursive function that takes an instance of `SubCategory` as a parameter to navigate down to the last leaf and return int.

Comment: Yes but I fret about a memory and I have to use the iteration what will be more dificult from recursive

Answer (score 0):

There is no 'last list' as there can be multiple elements at the same level!
To retrieve the one you've marked last you'd need a recursive loop, or you could just model it better!

Answer (score 0):

Ok I done it :) Thanks for your response.

```
public void showTree(List<SubCategory> child){

        for(int i=child.size()-1; i>=0; i--){
            if(!child.get(i).getSupCategory().isEmpty()){
                System.out.println(child.get(i).getNameOfCategory());
                showTree(child.get(i).getSupCategory());
            }
            else{
                System.out.println(child.get(i).getNameOfCategory());
                //child.remove(i);

            }
        }
```